# Error installing nvidia driver manually.

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I installed driver nvidia manually. I added:

- blacklist vga16fb
- blacklist nouveau
- blacklist rivafb
- blacklist nvidiafb
- blacklist rivatv

in file *blacklist.conf*

But when I install, I receive message:

*ERROR: Unable to load the kernel module ‘nvidia.ko’. This happens most frequently when this kernel module was built against the wrong or improperly configured kernel sources, with a version of gcc that differs from the one used to build the target kernel, or if a driver such as rivafb/nvidiafb is present and prevents the NVIDIA kernel module from obtaining ownership of the NVIDIA graphics device(s), or NVIDIA GPU installed in this system is not supported by this NVIDIA Linux graphics driver release.*

How I can fix it ?

Comment: Why did you install the Nvidia drivers manually instead of using the Additional Drivers utility? If you use Additional Drivers to install the proprietary Nvidia driver, it does all the configuration automatically. All you have to do is select the driver in Additional Drivers, click the **Apply Changes** button, and reboot.

Comment: @khanhdev which nvidia driver are you trying to install

Answer (score 0):

The driver will not be able to load during the current xsession because the conflicting driver is in use. Erase all that stuff you wrote to the blacklist file and reboot for your changes to take effect.